# Selecting @ parameters with SQL

Tags: sql-server, select, parameters

I'm doing a couple of tests regarding speed in SQL Server. To do it I have this simple query:

```
DECLARE @Time1 Date;
DECLARE @Time2 Date;

Set @Time1 = GETDATE();
-- Stuff happening
Set @Time2 = GETDATE();
```

Now I want to check the values of these properties (Time1 and Time2). I tried doing a `SELECT @Time1, Time2` but kept getting errors, so how can I check these values?

**EDIT**: as I mentioned to the accepted answer author, it was probably some syntax error that was eluding me from using a simple SELECT.
As for the fact the question is On Hold, I really don't see why as it seems a simple question to me. I created @parameters and set a value to them, then I want to check these values.

Comment: These are variables, not parameters. There's no problem with either parameters or variables in the SELECT clause so the question is unclear.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, you're right. As I said to RichBenner, I don't know I was not able to run the SELECT statement before... Must've been some minor syntax failing that eluded me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Doing a SELECT is not possible" - Who told you this?

```
DECLARE @Time1 DateTime;
DECLARE @Time2 DateTime;

Set @Time1 = GETDATE();
-- Stuff happening
Set @Time2 = GETDATE();

SELECT
@Time1
,@Time2
```

I've used this when analysing a large stored procedure, I put some datetime parameters at key points within the stored proc using getdate() and inserted them into an audit table at the end of the procedure. It was really handy for determining which part of the live stored procedure was going slowly for users.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I had an error when I tried the SELECT... Don't know what happened. Anyway, cheers!

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes

Comment: no worries, we all get these weird things happen at times. happy i could help. You probably want to declare the variables as datetime btw.

Answer (score 0):

First, perhaps, it is nessecarry to declare the @TimeX as TIME values - not as DATE ....

and than you con use PRINT

Print @Time1
Print @Time2

Comment: ofcourse you can use SELECT statment

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using parameters or variables in a SELECT clause. Arbitrary type changes are not a way to solve a problem either

Comment: you are right - but if you use DATE definition, as shown, the PRINT or SELECT statement shows the same Date two times - and therefor i wrote "PERHAPS" change the definition from DATE to TIME - or DATETIME, of course